# What is a "Top-level destination" in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-navigation-bar

I am working in Android Studio using Java. I want to implement a Navigation Drawer(those left to right swipe ones) with a Hamburger icon always on top. But there is some issue of "Top-level destination" without which that Hamburger icon doesn't show up. One of the solutions I found was to make that activity as my Launcher activity but I don't want that.

Can someone please explain to me what this "Top-level destination" phrase means and a possible workaround for my Navigation Drawer problem!!

This is my navigation layout

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".Main_Screen"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is the included appbar

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AppBarLayout.Primary">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You'd better show your key part of codes here. Otherwise, nobody can help you.

Comment: @wangwillway Anything else I should add?

Comment: When the drawer opens, you cannot see the hamburger icon. And you expect that 
 when the drawer opens, you still see the hamburger icon. Is this your problem?

Comment: No, I can't see the hamburger on the activity unless I make it my launcher activity. I can access the drawer with a right swipe but I want that hamburger icon to still show up without making the drawer activity as my launcher.
Basically, My app should open to a login page which then takes u to the activity with this drawer. So as my Login activity is my Launcher, I can't get the hamburger icon.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an activity named `LoginActivity`, where I just put a button, and created an activity named `MainActivity`,  where I put drawer. By clicking the button, I start the `MainActivity`.

In fact, I have not recurrented the problem you have said above.

But I have a suggestion that you may try creating the activity with drawer by file template not by hand, to avoid some mistakes that we have not discovered.

The step is: Right click the package name -> New -> Activity -> Navigation Drawer Activity.